# How to use a custom font style in flutter?

Tags: android, fonts, dart, flutter

I have already set on my pubspec.yaml the following code:

```
fonts:
- family: Roboto
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf
    - asset: fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
```

But I don't know to use, for example, the style "Roboto-Light.ttf" from Roboto in my widget. I tried this:

```
new ListTile(
          title: new Text(
            "Home",
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Roboto",
              fontSize: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I don't know how to access the style "Roboto-Light.ttf". How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Roboto is the default font of the Material style, there is no need to add it in pubspec.yaml.

To use the different variations, set a `TextStyle`

```
Text(
  'Home',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, // light
    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, // italic
  ),
);
```

I think thin is `FontWeight.w200`.

The **FontWeights** for the corresponding styles are mentioned in the **styles** section of the particular font in [**GoogleFonts**](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?query=source%20sans) website.

Comment: @boformer, how did you know this? Do you know the weight for semi-bold? Would all fonts with `-Light` in their title be used when you specify `FontWeight.w300` or is that specific to Roboto font?

Comment: No this is common standard: https://cssreference.io/property/font-weight/

Comment: 600 for Semi Bold

Comment: How to use font style bold?

Comment: How can I use font AvenirNext on iOS platform ? This font is supported in iOS but do I need to declare in assets ?

Answer (score 8):

In general, you can specify the font styles directly.

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  fonts:
    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
```

**Widget**

```
ListTile(
  title: Text(
    'Home',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, // -> Roboto-Light.ttf
      // fontWeight: FontWeight.w100 // -> Roboto-Thin.ttf
      fontSize: 60.0,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

## Declare and Access the font correctly.

> Declare the font path in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Follow the correct indentation.
For example, I have added **IndieFlower-Regular.ttf** file inside **fonts** folder. This is how my `pubspec.yaml` file looks like.

```
flutter:

 uses-material-design: true

 fonts:
   - family: Indies
   fonts:
     - asset: fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf
```

> Accessing the font in TextStyle

```
style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.green,
      fontSize: 30.0,
      fontFamily: 'Indies'
),
```

> For better understanding here is the picture which shows the font,
> pubspec.yaml and the output.

[image]

Comment: add indent for    fonts:

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this is only if you prefer using fonts from [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com/)**

One of the coolest and easiest way to use google fonts is to use the [google_fonts_package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts).

> The google_fonts package for Flutter allows you to easily use any of
>   the 960 fonts (and their variants) from fonts.google.com in your
>   Flutter app.With the google_fonts package, .ttf files do not need to
>   be stored in your assets folder and mapped in the pubspec. Instead,
>   they are fetched once via http at runtime, and cached in the app's
>   file system.

### Installation

1. add to pubspec.yaml

```
google_fonts: ^0.1.0
```

2. import

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
```

3. use your font e.g

```
Text("TestText", style:GoogleFonts.dancingScriptTextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    )
```

Although it mentions that it should not be used in production but I see an app deployed on both [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sneath.dadjokes) and [appstore](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/funny-dad-jokes/id1350314850)  by [Tim Sneath](https://github.com/timsneath) and works perfectly heres the [open source code](https://github.com/timsneath/dadjokes) hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If anyone want to change the default Flutter material font or use a custom font all over the app not in a specific widget,

first add downloaded font to pubspec.yaml

```
  fonts:
    - family: Outfit
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Outfit-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: fonts/Outfit-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
          style: italic
```

And then in the root of your project add this

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Custom Fonts',
  // Set Outfit as the default app font.
  theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Outfit'),
  home: const MyHomePage(),
);
```