# How to use a specific font from a list of fonts specified in a asset family in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Let's say i have added following lines to the pubspec.yaml file
fonts:

```
fonts:
- family: GreatVibes
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf
    - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Bold.ttf
```

I am using it in my app with the following lines of code.

```
new Text('My New Font',
        style: new TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'GreatVibes',
          fontSize: 16.0,
        )),
```

My question is that ,among the two .ttf files provided earlier, how does  flutter decides which file to use?

And Let's say if flutter decides to use GreatVibes-Bold.ttf, what can i do to make it use GreatVibes-regular.ttf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand these font things correctly - it has to be like this:

```
fonts:
- family: GreatVibes
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Regular.ttf
    - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
    - asset: fonts/GreatVibes-Italic.ttf
      style: italic
```

And then

```
new Text('My New Font',
    style: new TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontFamily: 'GreatVibes',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    )),
```

Comment: Sorry, it is just changing the weight of the font, what if i had placed italic style font in there, i want to give multiple font choices to the app user but if i have to specify 'family' for each of those fonts, it will become really hard to manage, that's the sole purpose of me asking this question.

Comment: I've edited answer - add option for italic. I don't know how you can put many different fonts in one family and work with them like as list

Comment: yes, the fact is that we can use any name for  family, it does not need to be same as the font's name, so if it has to choose b/w let say roboto and open sans, which of them will it choose

Answer (score 0):

you may use it directly into widget style,or using Theme object which i prefer to control overall app from one location, here an example for main.dart:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      **fontFamily: 'Lato'**),

 ....
  },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout these links :

[How to use a custom font style in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132135/how-to-use-a-custom-font-style-in-flutter)

https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: Are you sure, you said about flutter?

Comment: @Sandep, downvoting it, cause your solution is for Android. The question asked is for Flutter.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I changed it for flutter.

Comment: Don't use link to provide answer. You have comments for this purpose.