# Flutter: How to programmatically change the font weight

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and trying to build a text field with basic options just as in word (underlineing, changing fontsize and weight,...)

I was able to write a code for changing the font size and I tried the same for font weight, but i wasn´t able to make it work.
As I am also new to Stackoverflow I am having troubles with inserting my working code properly...

So my question is, if you could share your version of changing the fontweight of a text in a textfield via buttons just like in word.

Thank you!

Comment: See solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132135/how-to-use-a-custom-font-style-in-flutter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use stateful widget, then make variable:

```
bool isBold = false;
```

Then use a Text widget like this:

```
Text(‘hello’, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: isBold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal))
```

Next you need a button for user to toggle fontweight option:

```
MaterialButton(onPressed: () => setState(() => isBold = !isBold))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change fontweight of the textfield by using style property of Textfield
TextField(
....
style: fontweight=Fontweight.bold),
...