Custom font not showing on Android phone, but shows in Android simulator
I have made an app which uses a custom .ttf font. Unfortunately this font only works in the Android emulator. On my Samsung A52s phone (Android 14, One UI 6.1) it shows the default font.

Removing the app and install it again had no effect
Clearing the app cache had no effect
Using another font had no effect
Renaming the app bundle id e.g. com.company.app to com.company.app2 has no effect
Installing another app with the same font, shows the font without any issue
On iOS both the simulator and iPhone show the font without any issue
flutter clean had no effect
Rebuilding the app had no effect
Upgrading Android on the phone had no effect
Reboot had no effect

When you Google for "Flutter custom font not working" you get issues where the custom font did not work at all. In my case it is just the Android Phone.
Has anyone experienced the same?

Check this thread. It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366398/flutter-custom-font-not-displaying

This is super weird. When I removed the:
 textTheme: TextTheme(

From my theme it worked. Then when I restored the exact same code it worked as well.

To add a font to text you need to add font files in assets, mention those font and font family in pubspec.yaml file (check indentation) and then applying font using textStyle.
if you are using GoogleFonts package then you must give Internet permission in manifest file to make it work.

My issue is not getting custom fonts to work. It is why it does not work on a physical device while it does work on Android emulator.
